# Compiler refuses to get rid of the call to a function that does nothing

Tags: c++, c++11

The `add` method in the following code does nothing:

```
template <class StateNeighbor> struct NoGraph {
    using State = typename StateNeighbor::State;
    void add(const State &s) const {(void)s;}
    ...
};
```

Now, I have the following (the line with the comment is the important one):

```
template <class Open, class Heuristic,
          template <class State> class GoalHandler = SingleGoalHandler,
          template <class StateNeighbor> class Graph = NoGraph>
struct Astar {
    using Node = typename Open::Node;
    using CostType = typename Node::CostType;
    using NodeUP = typename Node::NodeUP;
    using State = typename Node::State;
    using StateUP = typename Node::StateUP;
    using Neighbor = typename State::Neighbor;

    Astar(const State &start, const GoalHandler<State> &goalHandler, Graph<Neighbor> &graph)
        : start_(start), goalHandler_(goalHandler), graph_(graph), oc_(),
          cur_(nullptr), children_() {
          graph_.add(start); // When Graph is instantiated to be NoGraph, the
                             // binary should be the same with or without this
                             // line!
    }
    ...
```

};

I instantiate `AStar` with `Graph=NoGraph` expecting that the compiler will get rid of the call to `add`. However, it does not happen: when I manually comment out that line, the binary changes.

I tried to reproduce this with a simpler example, but did not succeed. Here is my prototype:

```
struct A{
    void dump() const {std::cout << "This does something." << std::endl;}
};

struct B1 {
    void f(const A& a) const {(void)a;}
};
struct B2 {
    void f(const A& a) const {a.dump();}
};


template <class T1, class T2>
struct B{
    B(const T1& t1, T2& t2) : t1_(t1), t2_(t2) {
        t2.f(t1); // The binary is the same whether this line is present or not
    }
    void dump() const {
        std::cout << demangle(typeid(T2).name()) << std::endl;
    }
private:
    T1 t1_;
    T2 &t2_;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B1 b1;
    B<A,B1> b(a, b1);
    b.dump();
    return 0;
}
```

Just as the comment says, the compiler gets rid of the call to `f` in this case. So, why does the compiler refuse to get rid of the call to a function that does nothing in the original code? I am using `gcc` version 4.8.2 and compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11 -pedantic -O2`.

**UPDATE**: The problem has been solved. My assumption based on the comparison of binaries was wrong. After compiling with -DNDEBUG and running `strip` on the resulting binaries as suggested in one of the comments, the two binaries match.

Comment: The binary could have changed for unimportant reasons, such as debugging information. To reliably check whether the call was really removed, use the `-S` flag and inspect the resulting assembly.

Comment: @user4815162342 Could the debugging information be present when I use optimization flags such as -O2 or -O3? Also, the same compiler should have inserted this information for the prototype as well, in which case the binaries would be different for it also...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Yeah. To get rid of debug info you should compile with `-DNDEBUG` and then run `strip` on the resulting binary. But +1 to the idea of checking the assembly. That's really the only way to be sure.

Comment: my compiler (clang) changes the binary even if I compile the exact same file twice in a row…

Comment: Even if you manage to strip all debugging information, some sort of ancillary data is likely to be present. Inspecting the assembly to look for a simple function call is actually quite easy, you only need to look for the name of your function, you will either find instances where it is called or not.

Comment: @Cornstalks This is the solution!

Comment: @Cornstalks Checking the assembly is the only way to be sure if your method does not result in identical binaries. When it does, there isn't a reason to go for the assembly, is there?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: If they're identical, then there is no need to check the assembly.